# C++ inflect library

Tags: c++

I have a C++ written code that searches between a big document base (making use of CLucene).
I want to make it agnostic from singular and plural during searches and so I need to inflect words.
While working with python I used [inflect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect) a lot of times; is there any C++ library to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the search keyword you're looking for is "[stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)".  There's also a [C++ library](http://www.oleandersolutions.com/stemming/stemming.html) (BSD licensed) linked from the Wikipedia page (I can't comment on the library though, as I haven't used it).